# How does [ProtoInclude(20 ,typeof(child))] in ProtoBuf-net extend up the class hierarchy tree?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

*I have a class that needs to have all the properties of the parent and the grandparent, but I'm not sure how to structure this in protobuf-net.*

**Seemingly I should just be able to say:**

```
public class Child : Parent {
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   int childInt;
}

[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Child))]
public class Parent : GrandParent{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   int parentInt;
}

[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Parent))]
public class GrandParent {
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   int grandParentInt;
}
```

This should serialize all the ProtoMember integer members when I try to serialize an instance of the Child class, as far as I know.

Is this the correct way to do serialization inheritance in protobuf-net? *Help me Marc!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is an acceptable way to handle inheritance in protobuf-net. It will certainly *work*. In protobuf terms, that will be implemented *something like*:

```
message GrandParent {
    int grandParentInt = 1;
    optional Parent parent = 2;
}
message Parent {
    int parentInt = 1;
    optional Child child = 2;
}
message Child {
    int childInt = 1;
}
```

Personally, however, I'd be tempted to introduce a DTO type (rather than serializing your existing model) that simply exposes the required data in the simplest way possible - which *probably* means all at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so that will work! I made dummy tests, and all the **ProtoMembers of the GrandParent** will be serialized when you do just the **Parent's ProtoInclude statement.** This is nice.